# Overriding the encapsulated :host-style of external component

Tags: css, angular, encapsulation

Is it possible to override :host-styling of an external angular2-component?

We're making a library including a sidebar-component. This component has a default (fallback) background, but this should be overridable by css/theme used in the app.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar',
    styles: [`
        :host { background-color: green; }         
    `],
    template: `
        <h1>sidebar</h1>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class SideBarComponent { .... }
```

Main App css:

```
<style>
    sidebar {background: red; color: yellow; }
</style>
```

This returns a sidebar with green background and yellow text, but I want a red background...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edited:

As found on http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/: add an attribute to the body-tag:

```
<body override>
    <app></app>
</body>
```

And in your css: use a selector for this attribute:

```
[override] hello-world h1 {
    color:red;
}
```

This way, your css does not have to be parsed.

### Previous solution:

I've found a solution myself: instead of linking my (theming) css-file in index.html, which isn't parsed, I imported this particular css-file in the app.component.ts annotation.

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="/assets/style/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <app></app>
    </body>
</html>
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
import { ... }
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styles: [`
        @import "assets/style/theme.css";
    `], 
    template: `
        ...`,
})
export class AppComponent {...}
```

*theme.css:*

```
sidebar {background: red; }
```

Comment: This is a really useful and great find. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to overwrite styles set in a component's styles this way. See point 3 on the "Using Component Styles" section in the Component Styles docs  (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)

> 3. Our component's styles cannot be changed by changes to styles
>      elsewhere in the application.

Using `:host-context` is probably a nicer way to acheive this (although i have never tried myself).

Comment: _Our component's styles cannot be changed by changes to styles elsewhere in the application_ 
> not true, as in given example `color: yellow` does pass to the component

Comment: I come a bit late here.  I agree with @Benedikt Beun.  I think Point 3 is very misleading.   To further expand, `...elsewhere in the app` includes `styles.css` located at the top level, yes?  I've found that component styles can in fact  be overridden in `style.css`.   So if a component has a `h3` and it isn't given a specific style, its style will be set if `h3` is given a style in `style.css`.  If the component's `h3` does have a style, it can still be overridden in `style.css` by use of `!important`.

Answer (score -2):

You should try to check the same with `host-context`. As per [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#-host-context) `host-context` works just like the function form of `:host()`. It looks for a CSS class in any ancestor of the component host element, all the way up to the document root. It's useful when combined with another selector.

In the following example, we apply a `background-color` style to all `<h2>` elements inside the component, only if some ancestor element has the CSS class `theme-light`.

```
:host-context(.theme-light) h2 {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

Comment: Everything after "As per documentation" is copied from the link, but your answer reads like you wrote it yourself. That is not acceptable. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: (The text from the link is also inaccurate - evidently based on the description one could infer that :host-context() *doesn't* work like the functional :host().)